# How to stop infinite scaling

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am trying to have my circles scale down, and then stop after a certain size.
I want the cirlces to stay on my paper.js canvas, so that the user can create a sort of artistic sound image rendering.

I have tried using a while loop at the end of my code during the phase of iterating through each new created circle.

```
    var circles = [];

    function onKeyDown(event) {

        if (keyData[event.key]){
        var maxPoint = new Point(view.size.width, view.size.height);
        var randomPoint = Point.random();
        var point= maxPoint*randomPoint;
        var newCircle = new Path.Circle(point, 500);

        newCircle.fillColor =  keyData[event.key].color;
        keyData[event.key].sound.play();
        circles.push(newCircle);
        }
        else {

        }

    }



     function onFrame(event){
         for(var i = 0; i<circles.length; i++) {

             while ( circles[i].width> 50)
            {
                circles[i].fillColor.hue += 1;
                circles[i].scale(0.9)
            }
              // circles[i].fillColor.hue += 1;
             //circles[i].scale(0.9)
         }
     }
```

I wanted this to give me circles with a width of 50 in paper.js (i suppose pixels), but it just doesn't scale at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It took some time, but I figured it out, and it might help someone else struggling with Paper.js.
The function onFrame basically runs 60 times a second, like a loop.
So using while looped in a loop, which ran too much.
Using an If statement was a better option.

It was also necessary to find in Paper.js the proper size property, and with which element to link it. 
Path does not have a size property linked to it, but it can take bounds.
And bounds has a width property.

function onFrame(event){
          for(var i = 0; i

```
          console.log("\nbefore=  " + circles[i].bounds.width);

          if(circles[i].bounds.width>   80){
            circles[i].fillColor.hue += 6;
            circles[i].scale(0.95)

          }

          console.log("after =  " + circles[i].bounds.width);
      }
  }
```